# How to Access GNOME 3 Overview Mode?

Tags: keyboard, gnome, redhat-enterprise-linux

As the title states I'm looking for ways via the keyboard to open (and eventually disable) the overview mode for GNOME 3.

As it stands now I know of:

<kbd>Super</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

I know I can disable these keys via the `gsettings` command.

However someone on my team also mentioned they got the overview mode to open via the <kbd>F9</kbd> key. Is this possible? I could never seem to replicate it on my VM. I am using RHEL 8.2 with GNOME 3.32.2.

Thanks

Comment: Super Key (Ubuntu) is a toggle  - On then Off.   What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

All of GNOMEs shortcuts can be customized within Settings -> Keyboard -> Customize Shortcuts.

The one you're looking for is under System -> Show Workspaces.

Just click on it, press F9, click save, and you're done.